# Export Content from SDL Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, core-service, content-porter-2009, data-migration

Please let me explain the scenario:
We are using SDL Tridion 2011 , On our platform we have more then 100 publications out of these 100 Publication 1 publication want to leave the platform so our task is to backup there data and provide them in a readable format. 
From readable format I mean that the file should be in XML format and should have content + associated images + Meta data

This publication have huge data approx 10000 article with its 2Xbinaries.

Below are few approach we are trying, can you please help us and provide some pointer

Approach 1) Use content porter - Export all data using content porter and then create a custom tool to read this exported data and make it in readable format

Approach 2) Use core service API to read data of the publication and store in a readable format , this solution have a drawback as it will create a lot load on my live servers.

Can you please suggest any approach which can help in this scenario?

Comment: Content Porter exports the content as XML (just as it's stored in Tridion), why is that not "readable"?

Comment: When you say readable format what do you mean. There is one more option to do database restore on Tridion_cm database

Comment: Updated my question      From readable format I mean that the file should be in XML format and should have content + associated images + Meta data

Answer (score 2):

As asked in the comments, maybe you should edit your question and elaborate on what is a readable format to you, or at least give some more insight on what the goal is to export all this data.

I also don't quite see why approach #2 might create a huge load on your live servers, its apparoch isn't quite that different from #1 for when it comes to CM server and database load. The tool itself could be run on a different server so its load should not have impact on your live servers at all.

As to give you some more insigt to additional options, indeed as mentioned a database backup will also give you the data (not really in a readable format, unless you consider resporting it and connecting it to a CM instance, then you have it as readable as it was before).

Last option I can think of is, publish all that content to a website, you have it all in a readable format and ythere are several tools out there to archive websites.

Comment: Hi Bart thanks for reply i have edited my question as per your suggestion From readable format I mean that the file should be in XML format and should have content + associated images + Meta data

Answer (score 1):

There is also one more option that you could try. I personally never used Tridion WebDav functionality for storing content but you could copy the publication using WebDav to another location. When opened with WebDav the content is in "readable" state (XML).

But you should know that best way to go is database backup...

Comment: Thanks ognjen, I have tried webdav option its great but only have 1 single P1 issue i.e. in webdav downloaded XML it donot have the "Metadata" field and i have my content's published date in its metadata field